# Ember-CLI and slickgrid

Tags: ember-cli, slickgrid, ember-cli-addons

I would like to know the steps to include slickgrid to Ember-cli application?

I have added the "slickgrid": "~2.1.0" to bower.json.
and import statements to Brocfile.js. When I run the application, I get an error saying

> Slick is not defined

can anyone let me know if im missing something?